# Is there a performance/load difference between these 2 ways of using listeners in Java?

Tags: java, performance, events, listener

when working with listeners I always see code like this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel{

    public Test() {
        JPanel a = new JPanel();
        a.add(checkBoxMaker("foo"));
        add(a);
    }

    public JCheckBox checkBoxMaker(String name){
        JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox(name);

        // Like this (better)
        b.addItemListener(e -> System.out.println(e.getStateChange()));

        // Or like this
        b.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStateChange());
            }
        });
        return b;
    }
}
```

The way I think is better would be like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel{

    private ItemListener listener;

    public Test() {

        // So 
        listener = e -> System.out.println(e.getStateChange());

        // or so
        listener = new ItemListener(){

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
               System.out.println(e.getStateChange());
            }
        };

        JPanel a = new JPanel();
        a.add(checkBoxMaker("foo"));
        add(a);
    }

    public JCheckBox checkBoxMaker(String name){
        JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox(name);
        b.addItemListener(listener); //same listener declared once above
        return b;
    }
}
```

In the first snipped you can see that every Checkbox creation creates an ItemListener instance with the new keyword which is slow and costs ram I guess. While my version declares the Itemlistener once and uses it while creating a Checkbox.

I think instantiating something once is always better than doing it several times in a row.

So my question is: Is my way of thinking and working with listeners better in any way?

Extra question: What about Borders in a GUI application?
Is declaring a Border and using it multiple times over the UI more efficient than creating a Border every time with e.g. the BorderFactory for each JComponent?

regards

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that your way avoids the creation of extra listener objects.

But unless you have a truly insane number of checkboxes, this isn't going to matter at all. Java programs allocate thousands and thousands of objects. A few more or less is not something anyone is going to notice.

The drawback of your approach is that it only works if all the listeners really are identical. Often you'll want the listener to do something that's specific to that control. In the case of the checkbox control, you might want it to set a specific flag on some other object. So now the listeners are different: the Foo checkbox listener calls `Something.setFoo` and the Baz one calls `Something.setBaz`. Or maybe the listeners are just different because they capture different values from the context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very interested in how this differs technically. I think I will create a simple benchmark application for that to find out.

Comment: It will be hard to detect much of a difference. The JVM developers know that Java programs create lots of objects and have optimized the cost down to practically zero.